# Bash/Shell script find all files including keyword and of specific file type

Tags: macos, bash, shell, unix, find

How would I use find to find all files of a specific type e.g. `'*.mp3'` but specifically all files with any name including a keyword. e.g. `'black'`

All these files would be applicable:

```
    - blackDog.mp3
    - black dog.mp3
    - black rain.mp3
    - blackness.mp3
    - BlAcK.mp3
    - black.dog.mp3
    - black-dog.mp3
```

Here is my code that will find all `'*.mp3'` files but I just can't find the way to write all mp3's with any name that include a keyword `'black'`.

```
find ~/Desktop \( -type f -iname '*.mp3' \) -print0 |
while IFS= read -r -d '' f;
do mv -- "$f" ~/Music ;
done
```

Thank you very much for any help you're able to give me and please comment below for any clarification:

Comment: `-iname '*black*.mp3'` doesn't work for you?

Comment: @Barmar It does now that I know it, thank you ver much

Comment: Are all these files in the same directory? If so, the best way to do this would be simply `mv *black*.mp3 ~/Music`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
find ~/Desktop -type f -iname '*black*.mp3' -exec mv -- {} ~/Music \;
```

The filename pattern `*black*.mp3` matches any filename containing `black` and ending with `.mp3`.

Comment: Good suggestion on using `-exec` rather than a loop in the shell. Perhaps it would also be better to use `exec +` rather than `exec \;` to reduce the number of invocations of `mv`.

Comment: @TomFenech The documentation says that `+` appends all the filenames at the end. But with `mv` you need the destination directory at the end. GNU `mv` has `--target-directory` that can be used before the filenames to solve this, but I figured it would be better to keep it generic. Unless you're moving hundreds of files, the difference is probably negligible.